# Thinking Sphinx Error - ResponseError (searchd error (status: 1): index lead_delta: attribute 'user_id' not found):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I got following error while updating Lead model data:

Riddle::ResponseError (searchd error (status: 1): index lead_delta: attribute 'user_id' not found):
app/controllers/leads_controller.rb:88:in `block in update'

Everything was working fine until I changed search index in model, adding attribute user_id. After rebuilding sphinx index search is working Ok, but on update of Lead it shows error 500 and above mentioned message.

In Lead model I have following search indexes and attributes:

```
indexes client_name
indexes company
indexes product.name, :as => :lead_product 
indexes account_id
indexes email
indexes office_phone
indexes mobile_phone

has product_id, account_id, user_id

where "lead_converted = 0"

set_property :delta => :delayed
```

Controller Leads

def update

@lead = Lead.find params[:id] 
  respond_to do |format|

Line 88:  if @lead.update_attributes params[:lead]

I have following gem versions:

'thinking-sphinx', '2.0.3'

riddle (1.3.3)

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the `ts:rebuild` rake task? Or `ts:index`? The former is what's necessary, as it looks like the Sphinx daemon isn't aware of your new attribute (rebuild stops Sphinx, reindexes, and then starts Sphinx up again).

Comment: I am running ts:rebuild. And what is strange that search with attribute new "user_id" working fine, it is just update of Lead where this error appeared.